# Why do I get the Permission error when using npm install and how to fix that?

Tags: npm, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when i try to run npm install -g dbdocs, I get the following errors.

it happens when i did a recent update on windows10 system, i am using WSL, ubuntu 18.04. after updating of windows, the WSL becomes very strange(all npm, nvm and packages I installed before seem to disappear and pip in python's virtualenv point to the global site-packages instead of the one inside virtualenv, ...)

This issue is I try to use npm install a package called dbdocs. Not sure how to fix this, and make my original WSL back..

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/dbdocs
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run' -> '/usr/local/bin/dbdocs'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run' -> '/usr/local/bin/dbdocs'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run' -> '/usr/local/bin/dbdocs'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/local/bin/dbdocs' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run\' -> \'/usr/local/bin/dbdocs\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/dbdocs/bin/run',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/dbdocs' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/zhengxun/.npm/_logs/2020-06-12T05_50_40_668Z-debug.log
```

Comment: add sudo before indeed makes me install the packages but before updating windows, i never get this issue, want to know why and how to configure to consistently solve this issue